# call php function onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am working with html / php and I would like to realize the following situation:

[image]

If I click on the "green" button, it should start a php function with the parameter startLoop(5)

If I click on the "red" button, it should start a php function with the parameter startLoop(10)

```
<?php
function startLoop($loops) {
   for ($x = 0; $x < $loops; $x++) {
      $array[] = $x;
   }
   return $array;
}
?>
```

the orange area should show the result of the call functions linke this:

```
<?php
/** orange Area - all values of the array **/
for ($x = 0; $x < count($array); $x++) {
  echo $array[$x];
}
?>
```

and now is my problem, that i don't know, how I can realize it.
This all should happen without a site reload.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Without a page refresh, you'd need to make ajax calls to your PHP script.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: since PHP is server side, you cannot accomplish this without a page refresh, you'll need to use javascript (either to do the same as the PHP is expected to, or call a php script asynchronously)

Comment: can you show ne how I can solve my situation with a asynchronously php call? I didn't do this ever before :(

Comment: Honestly I'm not seeing why this logic needs to be server-side in the first place.  JavaScript is perfectly capable of having loops and creating arrays.  In any event, if what you're asking is how to interact with server-side code from client-side code then what you're looking for is tutorials on using AJAX with PHP.

Comment: if you use jQuery simplest example is to set ajax call method on `onclick` event of the element: `<tag ... onclick="$.get('test.php');">`. More examples are on the https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ and https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ pages.

Comment: If you absolutely must use PHP, and absolutely can't use AJAX, you can fudge this by making the orange area an iframe, and have your buttons target that iframe which is populated via a PHP script. It would be a kludge, and it would involve part of the page reloading, but not the whole page.

Comment: The best way is to make an ajax call to the function with the respective url or assign an annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="loop(5)">Green</button><br/>
        <button onclick="loop(10)">Red</button><br/>

        <input type="text" />

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            //$.get(url, data, callback)

            function loop(loopsFunctionParameter) {
                $.get(
                    "ajax.php",
                    {
                        loopsFromGet: loopsFunctionParameter
                    },
                    function(result) {
                        $("input").val(result);
                    }
                );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**ajax.php**

```
<?php
    function startLoop($loops) {
       for ($x = 0; $x < $loops; $x++) {
          $array[] = $x;
       }
       return $array;
    }

    if(isset($_GET["loopsFromGet"])) {
        $result = startLoop($_GET["loopsFromGet"]);
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

---

We have a JavaScript function that accepts the parameter *loops* and then it sends the GET request to the ajax.php script and passes the same parameter it accepts. ajax.php returns an array in JSON format but it can be anything really.

Notice: JavaScript is perfectly capable of doing the same thing.

Comment: Doesn't AJAX send `POST` data (not `GET`)?

Comment: @TheCodesee `$.get` and `$.post` are short-hand for ajax `GET` and `POST` requests, so both are available.

Comment: It can send both requests ($.get or $.post). You you get if you want to get some data like we do, and you use post if you want to insert some data to your database.

Comment: thanks a lot - works good. short question: `"ajax.php", { loops: loops }` - what is the first "loops" and what is the second loops?

Comment: First `loops` is from `$_GET["loops"]` and the seconds one is from JavaScript function `function loop(loops)`. I updated my answer.